# NetBeans icon: run project

Tags: java, netbeans

Whenever I press the icon run-project, netbeans runs another project, not the one in the main screen. Does any body know, how to fix it?

Comment: If you want to run the class which is currently being edited, just press SHIFT+F6 (on Windows).

Comment: Set the project you want run as the default project `Run | Set Main Project` and select the project you want

Comment: Because I change frequently the default project which I work on I prefer select ```Run``` from the contextual menu right-clicking on the project name in the Project side window.

Comment: Thank you guys!!! these you all mention works, and  is there  a way to make the Run Main Project Button (the green one with a play symbol) to run the class currently being edited?